# DB2 Can't connect to db with new user

Tags: db2

I have created a DB2 database, and I'm trying to create a new user.
Here the steps I made :
 - Creating an OS (Linux) user with root account (useradd myuser)
 - Giving a password to the new user (passwd myuser)
 - On IBM Data Studio, I added a new user and grant him connect to the database

But on Linux, with the user which owns the instance, I tried to connect to the database with the new user (db2 connect to MYDB user myuser), I've the following :
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you have any special characters in _myuser_'s password, by chance? Did you try to log into the shell with that user? Do you happen to have a password policy whereby the user must change its password on the first login?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, only letters and numbers. Yes I logged in with myuser, and there are no policy. Another idea ?

Comment: What DB2 version? Until DB2 9.7 fix pack 1 you could not have the password longer than 8 characters. And how long is the actual user name? I would limit that to 8 characters as well. The error is quite clear: the user authentication fails, and DB2 relies on the OS for authentication.

Comment: I'm in version 9.7. I resolved the problem, it was because the username was more than 8 caracters. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The answer might depend on the DB2 version. Until DB2 9.7 fix pack 1 you could not have the password longer than 8 characters. And how long is the actual user name? I would limit that to 8 characters as well. The error is quite clear: the user authentication fails, and DB2 relies on the OS for authentication.