# Can't Connect to Remote DB2 Database from CLI

Tags: linux, db2

I have DB2 installed on two computers. Server1 has version 10.1.0 and server2 has version 10.1.2. Both computers are on the same internal network.  I have a database on server1 that I want to access from server2.

On server1, I did the following:

```
CATALOG DATABASE dbfoobar AS db2foo ON /home/myuser
TERMINATE
db2stop
db2start
```

Then on server2, I did the following:

```
CATALOG TCPIP4 NODE db2foo REMOTE 192.168.x.x SERVER ####
TERMINATE
db2stop
db2start
CATALOG DATABASE dbfoobar AT NODE db2foo AUTHENTICATION SERVER
TERMINATE
db2stop
db2start
```

"####" is the port number.

But when I try to connect to dbfoobar from server2:

```
CONNECT TO dbfoobar USER myuser
```

The response I get after entering the password is:

```
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

The user account "myuser" exists on server1 and has permission to access the dbfoobar database.  I also logged in with the account on server1 directly, so I know the password is correct.  The output from netstat -nlp on server1 is:

```
tcp  0   0   0.0.0.0:####   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   24149/db2sysc 0
```

which means the port is open.

Any suggestions for solving this?

Comment: You didn't indicate your DB2 version. See if [this topic helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846625/db2-cant-connect-to-db-with-new-user).

Comment: Thanks mustaccio.  I don't think it applies.  I'm using version 10.1.0 on server1 and 10.1.2 on server2

Comment: I think on Linux the user ID is still limited to 8 characters. Try a shorter user ID.

Comment: The actual username is 8 characters.  I have local apps on server1 connecting successfully to the database in question with the username and password.

Comment: Check db2diag.log on the server you are connecting to for more details. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: Good tip on the error log.  I'm tracking down the error on the connection attempt: Password validation for user failed with rc = -2146500507.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to specify the password, try this (change the "mypassword" with the password for "myuser"):

```
CONNECT TO dbfoobar USER myuser using mypassword
```

Comment: I'm in another role and not using DB2 presently.  Can someone else please try this?